# How to change svg with colors

Tags: reactjs, svg

i am using reactjs, i have this svg,and i am looking fo a method to change the **width** of the colors according to some values from db.

This is the svg, you can copy it and past it in the browser inspector to see it :

```html
<svg width="328" height="164" viewBox="0 0 328 164" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g clip-path="url(#a)">
    <g clip-path="url(#b)">
      <mask id="c" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="31" y="30" width="266" height="133">
        <path d="M39.5 162.5c-4.418 0-8.025-3.585-7.759-7.995a132.507 132.507 0 0 1 38.567-85.697 132.502 132.502 0 0 1 187.384 0 132.517 132.517 0 0 1 38.567 85.697c.266 4.41-3.341 7.995-7.759 7.995H225c-4.418 0-7.938-3.602-8.603-7.97a52.978 52.978 0 0 0-14.92-29.507 53.007 53.007 0 0 0-74.954 0 53.027 53.027 0 0 0-14.92 29.507c-.665 4.368-4.185 7.97-8.603 7.97H39.5Z" fill="#D9D9D9" />
      </mask>
      <g mask="url(#c)">
        <path d="M31.5 162.5A132.505 132.505 0 0 1 89.352 53.029L164 162.5H31.5Z" fill="#4BC068" />
        <path d="M89.35 53.03a132.5 132.5 0 0 1 79.599-22.938L164 162.5 89.35 53.03Z" fill="#F5C500" />
        <path d="M168.923 30.091a132.496 132.496 0 0 1 123.058 98.101L164 162.5l4.923-132.409Z" fill="#FF8363" />
        <path d="M291.986 128.209a132.487 132.487 0 0 1 4.514 34.189L164 162.5l127.986-34.291Z" fill="#EB4A65" />
        <path opacity=".1" d="M31.5 162.5a132.503 132.503 0 0 1 81.794-122.414 132.503 132.503 0 0 1 173.12 71.708A132.5 132.5 0 0 1 296.5 162.5h-13.25A119.247 119.247 0 0 0 118.365 52.327 119.25 119.25 0 0 0 44.75 162.5H31.5Z" fill="#343A40" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <path d="M131.436 65.074a.354.354 0 0 1 .665-.24l37.252 91.518a4.45 4.45 0 1 1-8.365 3.008l-29.552-94.286Z" fill="#030F40" />
    <circle cx="165.176" cy="158.038" r="2.529" transform="rotate(-19.65 165.176 158.038)" fill="#F8F9FA" />
    <path d="M16.503 156.624v-3.792c0-1.524-1.104-2.448-2.472-2.448-1.356 0-2.46.924-2.46 2.448v3.792c0 1.524 1.104 2.448 2.46 2.448 1.368 0 2.472-.924 2.472-2.448Zm-1.224-.036c0 .816-.468 1.392-1.248 1.392-.768 0-1.236-.576-1.236-1.392v-3.72c0-.816.468-1.392 1.236-1.392.78 0 1.248.576 1.248 1.392v3.72ZM57.625 46v-1.092h-3.48l2.676-3.276c.528-.648.804-1.092.804-1.848 0-1.476-1.008-2.4-2.472-2.4-1.452 0-2.484.96-2.484 2.412h1.224c0-.96.612-1.32 1.26-1.32.792 0 1.248.528 1.248 1.296 0 .432-.132.744-.456 1.14l-3.288 3.996V46h4.968Zm6.458-2.532c0-1.5-1.008-2.472-2.244-2.472-.264 0-.528.036-.756.132l1.836-3.672h-1.308l-1.944 3.96c-.372.744-.636 1.404-.636 2.1 0 1.584 1.056 2.556 2.532 2.556s2.52-1.032 2.52-2.604Zm-1.224.024c0 .912-.54 1.488-1.308 1.488s-1.296-.576-1.296-1.488c0-.924.528-1.476 1.296-1.476.816 0 1.308.636 1.308 1.476ZM74.072 46l-2.376-3.696 2.112-2.388H72.32l-2.364 2.808v-5.268h-1.224V46h1.224v-1.788l.9-1.02L72.56 46h1.512Zm5.458-.036v-6.048h-1.188v.648c-.456-.552-.948-.72-1.596-.72-.612 0-1.128.192-1.464.528-.588.588-.684 1.44-.684 2.472s.096 1.884.684 2.472c.336.336.84.54 1.452.54.624 0 1.128-.168 1.572-.696v.78c0 .816-.396 1.548-1.428 1.548-.6 0-.936-.18-1.32-.54l-.78.78c.636.588 1.224.804 2.148.804 1.62 0 2.604-1.08 2.604-2.568Zm-1.224-3.12c0 .96-.132 1.908-1.236 1.908s-1.248-.948-1.248-1.908.144-1.908 1.248-1.908 1.236.948 1.236 1.908Zm78.37-25.128v-1.14h-.912v-1.992h-1.188v1.992h-2.124l3-6.12h-1.32l-3.012 6.12v1.14h3.456V19h1.188v-1.284h.912Zm6.219-1.116c0-1.056-.468-1.692-1.2-2.016.66-.324 1.068-.912 1.068-1.824 0-1.416-1.032-2.388-2.484-2.388-1.368 0-2.436.876-2.508 2.328h1.224c.06-.756.54-1.224 1.284-1.224.696 0 1.26.456 1.26 1.32 0 .78-.408 1.296-1.296 1.296h-.204v1.068h.204c.96 0 1.428.54 1.428 1.404 0 .9-.6 1.416-1.392 1.416-.708 0-1.344-.384-1.392-1.296h-1.224c.048 1.668 1.248 2.4 2.616 2.4 1.428 0 2.616-.84 2.616-2.484Zm9.977 2.4-2.376-3.696 2.112-2.388h-1.488l-2.364 2.808v-5.268h-1.224V19h1.224v-1.788l.9-1.02L171.36 19h1.512Zm5.458-.036v-6.048h-1.188v.648c-.456-.552-.948-.72-1.596-.72-.612 0-1.128.192-1.464.528-.588.588-.684 1.44-.684 2.472s.096 1.884.684 2.472c.336.336.84.54 1.452.54.624 0 1.128-.168 1.572-.696v.78c0 .816-.396 1.548-1.428 1.548-.6 0-.936-.18-1.32-.54l-.78.78c.636.588 1.224.804 2.148.804 1.62 0 2.604-1.08 2.604-2.568Zm-1.224-3.12c0 .96-.132 1.908-1.236 1.908s-1.248-.948-1.248-1.908.144-1.908 1.248-1.908 1.236.948 1.236 1.908Zm127.238 104.704v-1.092h-5.088v2.436h1.176v-1.344h2.604L300.168 128h1.32l2.856-7.452Zm6.458 0v-1.092h-5.088v2.436h1.176v-1.344h2.604L306.626 128h1.32l2.856-7.452Zm9.87 7.452-2.376-3.696 2.112-2.388h-1.488l-2.364 2.808v-5.268h-1.224V128h1.224v-1.788l.9-1.02L319.16 128h1.512Zm5.457-.036v-6.048h-1.188v.648c-.456-.552-.948-.72-1.596-.72-.612 0-1.128.192-1.464.528-.588.588-.684 1.44-.684 2.472s.096 1.884.684 2.472c.336.336.84.54 1.452.54.624 0 1.128-.168 1.572-.696v.78c0 .816-.396 1.548-1.428 1.548-.6 0-.936-.18-1.32-.54l-.78.78c.636.588 1.224.804 2.148.804 1.62 0 2.604-1.08 2.604-2.568Zm-1.224-3.12c0 .96-.132 1.908-1.236 1.908s-1.248-.948-1.248-1.908.144-1.908 1.248-1.908 1.236.948 1.236 1.908Zm-17.573 30.744c0-1.02-.576-1.644-1.176-2.004.552-.336 1.032-.936 1.032-1.836 0-1.428-1.104-2.364-2.496-2.364s-2.484.936-2.484 2.364c0 .9.48 1.5 1.032 1.836-.6.36-1.176.984-1.176 2.004 0 1.548 1.164 2.484 2.628 2.484 1.464 0 2.64-.936 2.64-2.484Zm-1.236-.024c0 .792-.612 1.416-1.404 1.416a1.393 1.393 0 0 1-1.404-1.416c0-.792.612-1.428 1.404-1.428.792 0 1.404.636 1.404 1.428Zm-.132-3.78c0 .756-.528 1.296-1.272 1.296s-1.26-.54-1.26-1.296c0-.744.516-1.308 1.26-1.308s1.272.564 1.272 1.308Zm7.97 4.932v-1.14h-.912v-1.992h-1.188v1.992h-2.124l3-6.12h-1.32l-3.012 6.12v1.14h3.456V158h1.188v-1.284h.912Zm6.795 1.284-2.376-3.696 2.112-2.388h-1.488l-2.364 2.808v-5.268h-1.224V158h1.224v-1.788l.9-1.02 1.704 2.808h1.512Zm5.458-.036v-6.048h-1.188v.648c-.456-.552-.948-.72-1.596-.72-.612 0-1.128.192-1.464.528-.588.588-.684 1.44-.684 2.472s.096 1.884.684 2.472c.336.336.84.54 1.452.54.624 0 1.128-.168 1.572-.696v.78c0 .816-.396 1.548-1.428 1.548-.6 0-.936-.18-1.32-.54l-.78.78c.636.588 1.224.804 2.148.804 1.62 0 2.604-1.08 2.604-2.568Zm-1.224-3.12c0 .96-.132 1.908-1.236 1.908s-1.248-.948-1.248-1.908.144-1.908 1.248-1.908 1.236.948 1.236 1.908Z" fill="#ABAFBF" />
  </g>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="a">
      <path fill="#fff" d="M.5 0h327v164H.5z" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="b">
      <path fill="#fff" d="M31.5 30h265v134h-265z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

this is the example of the result :

```html
<svg width="328" height="164" viewBox="0 0 328 164" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g clip-path="url(#a)"><g clip-path="url(#b)"><mask id="c" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="31" y="30" width="266" height="133" style="mask-type:alpha"><path d="M39.5 162.5c-4.418 0-8.025-3.585-7.759-7.995a132.507 132.507 0 0 1 38.567-85.697 132.502 132.502 0 0 1 187.384 0 132.517 132.517 0 0 1 38.567 85.697c.266 4.41-3.341 7.995-7.759 7.995H225c-4.418 0-7.938-3.602-8.603-7.97a52.978 52.978 0 0 0-14.92-29.507 53.007 53.007 0 0 0-74.954 0 53.027 53.027 0 0 0-14.92 29.507c-.665 4.368-4.185 7.97-8.603 7.97H39.5Z" fill="#D9D9D9"/></mask><g mask="url(#c)"><path d="M31.5 162.5A132.505 132.505 0 0 1 89.352 53.029L164 162.5H31.5Z" fill="#4BC068"/><path d="M36.746 126.547c24.266-87.81 103.9-97.513 132.203-96.455L164 162.5Z" fill="#f5c500"/><path d="M168.923 30.091a132.496 132.496 0 0 1 123.058 98.101L164 162.5l4.923-132.409Z" fill="#FF8363"/><path d="M188.29 31.506c105.719 19.442 108.2 119.348 108.21 130.892L164 162.5Z" fill="#eb4a65"/><path opacity=".1" d="M31.5 162.5a132.503 132.503 0 0 1 81.794-122.414 132.503 132.503 0 0 1 173.12 71.708A132.5 132.5 0 0 1 296.5 162.5h-13.25A119.247 119.247 0 0 0 118.365 52.327 119.25 119.25 0 0 0 44.75 162.5H31.5Z" fill="#343A40"/></g></g><path d="M131.436 65.074a.354.354 0 0 1 .665-.24l37.252 91.518a4.45 4.45 0 1 1-8.365 3.008l-29.552-94.286Z" fill="#030F40"/><circle cx="165.176" cy="158.038" r="2.529" transform="rotate(-19.65 165.176 158.038)" fill="#F8F9FA"/><path d="M16.503 156.624v-3.792c0-1.524-1.104-2.448-2.472-2.448-1.356 0-2.46.924-2.46 2.448v3.792c0 1.524 1.104 2.448 2.46 2.448 1.368 0 2.472-.924 2.472-2.448Zm-1.224-.036c0 .816-.468 1.392-1.248 1.392-.768 0-1.236-.576-1.236-1.392v-3.72c0-.816.468-1.392 1.236-1.392.78 0 1.248.576 1.248 1.392v3.72ZM57.625 46v-1.092h-3.48l2.676-3.276c.528-.648.804-1.092.804-1.848 0-1.476-1.008-2.4-2.472-2.4-1.452 0-2.484.96-2.484 2.412h1.224c0-.96.612-1.32 1.26-1.32.792 0 1.248.528 1.248 1.296 0 .432-.132.744-.456 1.14l-3.288 3.996V46h4.968Zm6.458-2.532c0-1.5-1.008-2.472-2.244-2.472-.264 0-.528.036-.756.132l1.836-3.672h-1.308l-1.944 3.96c-.372.744-.636 1.404-.636 2.1 0 1.584 1.056 2.556 2.532 2.556s2.52-1.032 2.52-2.604Zm-1.224.024c0 .912-.54 1.488-1.308 1.488s-1.296-.576-1.296-1.488c0-.924.528-1.476 1.296-1.476.816 0 1.308.636 1.308 1.476ZM74.072 46l-2.376-3.696 2.112-2.388H72.32l-2.364 2.808v-5.268h-1.224V46h1.224v-1.788l.9-1.02L72.56 46h1.512Zm5.458-.036v-6.048h-1.188v.648c-.456-.552-.948-.72-1.596-.72-.612 0-1.128.192-1.464.528-.588.588-.684 1.44-.684 2.472s.096 1.884.684 2.472c.336.336.84.54 1.452.54.624 0 1.128-.168 1.572-.696v.78c0 .816-.396 1.548-1.428 1.548-.6 0-.936-.18-1.32-.54l-.78.78c.636.588 1.224.804 2.148.804 1.62 0 2.604-1.08 2.604-2.568Zm-1.224-3.12c0 .96-.132 1.908-1.236 1.908s-1.248-.948-1.248-1.908.144-1.908 1.248-1.908 1.236.948 1.236 1.908Zm78.37-25.128v-1.14h-.912v-1.992h-1.188v1.992h-2.124l3-6.12h-1.32l-3.012 6.12v1.14h3.456V19h1.188v-1.284h.912Zm6.219-1.116c0-1.056-.468-1.692-1.2-2.016.66-.324 1.068-.912 1.068-1.824 0-1.416-1.032-2.388-2.484-2.388-1.368 0-2.436.876-2.508 2.328h1.224c.06-.756.54-1.224 1.284-1.224.696 0 1.26.456 1.26 1.32 0 .78-.408 1.296-1.296 1.296h-.204v1.068h.204c.96 0 1.428.54 1.428 1.404 0 .9-.6 1.416-1.392 1.416-.708 0-1.344-.384-1.392-1.296h-1.224c.048 1.668 1.248 2.4 2.616 2.4 1.428 0 2.616-.84 2.616-2.484Zm9.977 2.4-2.376-3.696 2.112-2.388h-1.488l-2.364 2.808v-5.268h-1.224V19h1.224v-1.788l.9-1.02L171.36 19h1.512Zm5.458-.036v-6.048h-1.188v.648c-.456-.552-.948-.72-1.596-.72-.612 0-1.128.192-1.464.528-.588.588-.684 1.44-.684 2.472s.096 1.884.684 2.472c.336.336.84.54 1.452.54.624 0 1.128-.168 1.572-.696v.78c0 .816-.396 1.548-1.428 1.548-.6 0-.936-.18-1.32-.54l-.78.78c.636.588 1.224.804 2.148.804 1.62 0 2.604-1.08 2.604-2.568Zm-1.224-3.12c0 .96-.132 1.908-1.236 1.908s-1.248-.948-1.248-1.908.144-1.908 1.248-1.908 1.236.948 1.236 1.908Zm127.238 104.704v-1.092h-5.088v2.436h1.176v-1.344h2.604L300.168 128h1.32l2.856-7.452Zm6.458 0v-1.092h-5.088v2.436h1.176v-1.344h2.604L306.626 128h1.32l2.856-7.452Zm9.87 7.452-2.376-3.696 2.112-2.388h-1.488l-2.364 2.808v-5.268h-1.224V128h1.224v-1.788l.9-1.02L319.16 128h1.512Zm5.457-.036v-6.048h-1.188v.648c-.456-.552-.948-.72-1.596-.72-.612 0-1.128.192-1.464.528-.588.588-.684 1.44-.684 2.472s.096 1.884.684 2.472c.336.336.84.54 1.452.54.624 0 1.128-.168 1.572-.696v.78c0 .816-.396 1.548-1.428 1.548-.6 0-.936-.18-1.32-.54l-.78.78c.636.588 1.224.804 2.148.804 1.62 0 2.604-1.08 2.604-2.568Zm-1.224-3.12c0 .96-.132 1.908-1.236 1.908s-1.248-.948-1.248-1.908.144-1.908 1.248-1.908 1.236.948 1.236 1.908Zm-17.573 30.744c0-1.02-.576-1.644-1.176-2.004.552-.336 1.032-.936 1.032-1.836 0-1.428-1.104-2.364-2.496-2.364s-2.484.936-2.484 2.364c0 .9.48 1.5 1.032 1.836-.6.36-1.176.984-1.176 2.004 0 1.548 1.164 2.484 2.628 2.484 1.464 0 2.64-.936 2.64-2.484Zm-1.236-.024c0 .792-.612 1.416-1.404 1.416a1.393 1.393 0 0 1-1.404-1.416c0-.792.612-1.428 1.404-1.428.792 0 1.404.636 1.404 1.428Zm-.132-3.78c0 .756-.528 1.296-1.272 1.296s-1.26-.54-1.26-1.296c0-.744.516-1.308 1.26-1.308s1.272.564 1.272 1.308Zm7.97 4.932v-1.14h-.912v-1.992h-1.188v1.992h-2.124l3-6.12h-1.32l-3.012 6.12v1.14h3.456V158h1.188v-1.284h.912Zm6.795 1.284-2.376-3.696 2.112-2.388h-1.488l-2.364 2.808v-5.268h-1.224V158h1.224v-1.788l.9-1.02 1.704 2.808h1.512Zm5.458-.036v-6.048h-1.188v.648c-.456-.552-.948-.72-1.596-.72-.612 0-1.128.192-1.464.528-.588.588-.684 1.44-.684 2.472s.096 1.884.684 2.472c.336.336.84.54 1.452.54.624 0 1.128-.168 1.572-.696v.78c0 .816-.396 1.548-1.428 1.548-.6 0-.936-.18-1.32-.54l-.78.78c.636.588 1.224.804 2.148.804 1.62 0 2.604-1.08 2.604-2.568Zm-1.224-3.12c0 .96-.132 1.908-1.236 1.908s-1.248-.948-1.248-1.908.144-1.908 1.248-1.908 1.236.948 1.236 1.908Z" fill="#ABAFBF"/></g><defs><clipPath id="a"><path fill="#fff" d="M.5 0h327v164H.5z"/></clipPath><clipPath id="b"><path fill="#fff" d="M31.5 30h265v134h-265z"/></clipPath></defs></svg>
```

Comment: The way you have it right now it's almost impossible to achieve what you want. I would take a different aproach that would simplify your code a lot

Comment: @enxaneta ?????

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it. For each color I'm using a path (a semicircle) with a very thick stroke (stroke-width="95").

Since I'm using this path 4 times I'll put it in the defs and I'll reuse it with `<use>`

The use elements have a `stroke-dasharray` attribute. The dasharray is an array of values where (in this case) the first value is the stroke and the second one is the gap.

Please observe that the path has `pathLength="100"` and the the sum of the values of the dasharray is also 100. For example if stroke-dasharray="30 70" the stroke (the color) is 30 the gap is 70 and both stroke + gap = 100.

For the second color you will need to offset the first dash so you will need a stroke-dashoffset whose value is the negative of the previous dash.

For example if the previous stroke-dasharray="**30** 70" the value for the stroke-dashoffset="-30"

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 328 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <path id="pth" d="M70 162.5A95 95 0 0 1 260,162.5" stroke-width="95" pathLength="100" fill="none" />
  </defs>
  <mask id="c" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <path d="M39.5 162.5c-4.418 0-8.025-3.585-7.759-7.995a132.507 132.507 0 0 1 38.567-85.697 132.502 132.502 0 0 1 187.384 0 132.517 132.517 0 0 1 38.567 85.697c.266 4.41-3.341 7.995-7.759 7.995H225c-4.418 0-7.938-3.602-8.603-7.97a52.978 52.978 0 0 0-14.92-29.507 53.007 53.007 0 0 0-74.954 0 53.027 53.027 0 0 0-14.92 29.507c-.665 4.368-4.185 7.97-8.603 7.97H39.5Z" fill="white" />
  </mask>

  <g fill="none" mask="url(#c)">
    <use href="#pth" stroke="green" stroke-dasharray="30 70" />
    <use href="#pth" stroke="gold" stroke-dasharray="20 80" stroke-dashoffset="-30" />
    <use href="#pth" stroke="salmon" stroke-dasharray="40 80" stroke-dashoffset="-50" />
    <use href="#pth" stroke="red" stroke-dasharray="10 90" stroke-dashoffset="-90" />

    <path opacity=".1" d="M31.5 162.5a132.503 132.503 0 0 1 81.794-122.414 132.503 132.503 0 0 1 173.12 71.708A132.5 132.5 0 0 1 296.5 162.5h-13.25A119.247 119.247 0 0 0 118.365 52.327 119.25 119.25 0 0 0 44.75 162.5H31.5Z" fill="#343A40" />
  </g>
<!--
  <path d="M131.436 65.074a.354.354 0 0 1 .665-.24l37.252 91.518a4.45 4.45 0 1 1-8.365 3.008l-29.552-94.286Z" fill="#030F40" />
  <circle cx="165.176" cy="158.038" r="2.529" transform="rotate(-19.65 165.176 158.038)" fill="#F8F9FA" />-->
</svg>
```

In the code I'm using the same mask as you do and the same shadow.

The code for the example above is simplified but you can uncomment the needle and the hub as you have it in your code.

As for the text you may want to delete the path you have and use `<text>` elements so that you can add the values where needed.

Comment: thanks for sharing, but  it is not practical when you want to put dynamic values from db

Comment: Yes it is. For example for the first color if value is 30 stroke-dasharray="30 100-30" and stroke-dashoffset="30 * -1" For the last color the value is 10 stroke-dasharray="10 100-10" and stroke-dashoffset is (30 +20 +40) * -1 = -90 where 30, 20 and 40 are the previous values

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is changing the `fill` attribute in path's with the values that you get from database, example:

```
<path d="M131.436 65.074a.354.354 0 0 1 .665-.24l37.252 91.518a4.45 4.45 0 1 1-8.365 3.008l-29.552-94.286Z" fill="colorFromDb"></path>
```

Comment: it's not the color that i want to change, it"s the width of each color

Answer (score 0):

could you do like that you can pass the width and height to SVG icon component.

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-roman-fvlu0m)

```
export const ExampleIcon = ({ size }) => (
  <svg
    width={size || "328"}
    height={size || "164"}
    viewBox="0 0 328 164"
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <g clip-path="url(#a)">
      <g clip-path="url(#b)">
        <mask
          id="c"
          // style="mask-type:alpha"
          maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
          x="31"
          y="30"
          width="266"
          height="133"
        >
          <path
            d="M39.5 162.5c-4.418 0-8.025-3.585-7.759-7.995a132.507 132.507 0 0 1 38.567-85.697 132.502 132.502 0 0 1 187.384 0 132.517 132.517 0 0 1 38.567 85.697c.266 4.41-3.341 7.995-7.759 7.995H225c-4.418 0-7.938-3.602-8.603-7.97a52.978 52.978 0 0 0-14.92-29.507 53.007 53.007 0 0 0-74.954 0 53.027 53.027 0 0 0-14.92 29.507c-.665 4.368-4.185 7.97-8.603 7.97H39.5Z"
            fill="#D9D9D9"
          />
        </mask>
        <g mask="url(#c)">
          <path
            d="M31.5 162.5A132.505 132.505 0 0 1 89.352 53.029L164 162.5H31.5Z"
            fill="#4BC068"
          />
          <path
            d="M89.35 53.03a132.5 132.5 0 0 1 79.599-22.938L164 162.5 89.35 53.03Z"
            fill="#F5C500"
          />
          <path
            d="M168.923 30.091a132.496 132.496 0 0 1 123.058 98.101L164 162.5l4.923-132.409Z"
            fill="#FF8363"
          />
          <path
            d="M291.986 128.209a132.487 132.487 0 0 1 4.514 34.189L164 162.5l127.986-34.291Z"
            fill="#EB4A65"
          />
          <path
            opacity=".1"
            d="M31.5 162.5a132.503 132.503 0 0 1 81.794-122.414 132.503 132.503 0 0 1 173.12 71.708A132.5 132.5 0 0 1 296.5 162.5h-13.25A119.247 119.247 0 0 0 118.365 52.327 119.25 119.25 0 0 0 44.75 162.5H31.5Z"
            fill="#343A40"
          />
        </g>
      </g>
      <path
        d="M131.436 65.074a.354.354 0 0 1 .665-.24l37.252 91.518a4.45 4.45 0 1 1-8.365 3.008l-29.552-94.286Z"
        fill="#030F40"
      />
      <circle
        cx="165.176"
        cy="158.038"
        r="2.529"
        transform="rotate(-19.65 165.176 158.038)"
        fill="#F8F9FA"
      />
      <path
        d="M16.503 156.624v-3.792c0-1.524-1.104-2.448-2.472-2.448-1.356 0-2.46.924-2.46 2.448v3.792c0 1.524 1.104 2.448 2.46 2.448 1.368 0 2.472-.924 2.472-2.448Zm-1.224-.036c0 .816-.468 1.392-1.248 1.392-.768 0-1.236-.576-1.236-1.392v-3.72c0-.816.468-1.392 1.236-1.392.78 0 1.248.576 1.248 1.392v3.72ZM57.625 46v-1.092h-3.48l2.676-3.276c.528-.648.804-1.092.804-1.848 0-1.476-1.008-2.4-2.472-2.4-1.452 0-2.484.96-2.484 2.412h1.224c0-.96.612-1.32 1.26-1.32.792 0 1.248.528 1.248 1.296 0 .432-.132.744-.456 1.14l-3.288 3.996V46h4.968Zm6.458-2.532c0-1.5-1.008-2.472-2.244-2.472-.264 0-.528.036-.756.132l1.836-3.672h-1.308l-1.944 3.96c-.372.744-.636 1.404-.636 2.1 0 1.584 1.056 2.556 2.532 2.556s2.52-1.032 2.52-2.604Zm-1.224.024c0 .912-.54 1.488-1.308 1.488s-1.296-.576-1.296-1.488c0-.924.528-1.476 1.296-1.476.816 0 1.308.636 1.308 1.476ZM74.072 46l-2.376-3.696 2.112-2.388H72.32l-2.364 2.808v-5.268h-1.224V46h1.224v-1.788l.9-1.02L72.56 46h1.512Zm5.458-.036v-6.048h-1.188v.648c-.456-.552-.948-.72-1.596-.72-.612 0-1.128.192-1.464.528-.588.588-.684 1.44-.684 2.472s.096 1.884.684 2.472c.336.336.84.54 1.452.54.624 0 1.128-.168 1.572-.696v.78c0 .816-.396 1.548-1.428 1.548-.6 0-.936-.18-1.32-.54l-.78.78c.636.588 1.224.804 2.148.804 1.62 0 2.604-1.08 2.604-2.568Zm-1.224-3.12c0 .96-.132 1.908-1.236 1.908s-1.248-.948-1.248-1.908.144-1.908 1.248-1.908 1.236.948 1.236 1.908Zm78.37-25.128v-1.14h-.912v-1.992h-1.188v1.992h-2.124l3-6.12h-1.32l-3.012 6.12v1.14h3.456V19h1.188v-1.284h.912Zm6.219-1.116c0-1.056-.468-1.692-1.2-2.016.66-.324 1.068-.912 1.068-1.824 0-1.416-1.032-2.388-2.484-2.388-1.368 0-2.436.876-2.508 2.328h1.224c.06-.756.54-1.224 1.284-1.224.696 0 1.26.456 1.26 1.32 0 .78-.408 1.296-1.296 1.296h-.204v1.068h.204c.96 0 1.428.54 1.428 1.404 0 .9-.6 1.416-1.392 1.416-.708 0-1.344-.384-1.392-1.296h-1.224c.048 1.668 1.248 2.4 2.616 2.4 1.428 0 2.616-.84 2.616-2.484Zm9.977 2.4-2.376-3.696 2.112-2.388h-1.488l-2.364 2.808v-5.268h-1.224V19h1.224v-1.788l.9-1.02L171.36 19h1.512Zm5.458-.036v-6.048h-1.188v.648c-.456-.552-.948-.72-1.596-.72-.612 0-1.128.192-1.464.528-.588.588-.684 1.44-.684 2.472s.096 1.884.684 2.472c.336.336.84.54 1.452.54.624 0 1.128-.168 1.572-.696v.78c0 .816-.396 1.548-1.428 1.548-.6 0-.936-.18-1.32-.54l-.78.78c.636.588 1.224.804 2.148.804 1.62 0 2.604-1.08 2.604-2.568Zm-1.224-3.12c0 .96-.132 1.908-1.236 1.908s-1.248-.948-1.248-1.908.144-1.908 1.248-1.908 1.236.948 1.236 1.908Zm127.238 104.704v-1.092h-5.088v2.436h1.176v-1.344h2.604L300.168 128h1.32l2.856-7.452Zm6.458 0v-1.092h-5.088v2.436h1.176v-1.344h2.604L306.626 128h1.32l2.856-7.452Zm9.87 7.452-2.376-3.696 2.112-2.388h-1.488l-2.364 2.808v-5.268h-1.224V128h1.224v-1.788l.9-1.02L319.16 128h1.512Zm5.457-.036v-6.048h-1.188v.648c-.456-.552-.948-.72-1.596-.72-.612 0-1.128.192-1.464.528-.588.588-.684 1.44-.684 2.472s.096 1.884.684 2.472c.336.336.84.54 1.452.54.624 0 1.128-.168 1.572-.696v.78c0 .816-.396 1.548-1.428 1.548-.6 0-.936-.18-1.32-.54l-.78.78c.636.588 1.224.804 2.148.804 1.62 0 2.604-1.08 2.604-2.568Zm-1.224-3.12c0 .96-.132 1.908-1.236 1.908s-1.248-.948-1.248-1.908.144-1.908 1.248-1.908 1.236.948 1.236 1.908Zm-17.573 30.744c0-1.02-.576-1.644-1.176-2.004.552-.336 1.032-.936 1.032-1.836 0-1.428-1.104-2.364-2.496-2.364s-2.484.936-2.484 2.364c0 .9.48 1.5 1.032 1.836-.6.36-1.176.984-1.176 2.004 0 1.548 1.164 2.484 2.628 2.484 1.464 0 2.64-.936 2.64-2.484Zm-1.236-.024c0 .792-.612 1.416-1.404 1.416a1.393 1.393 0 0 1-1.404-1.416c0-.792.612-1.428 1.404-1.428.792 0 1.404.636 1.404 1.428Zm-.132-3.78c0 .756-.528 1.296-1.272 1.296s-1.26-.54-1.26-1.296c0-.744.516-1.308 1.26-1.308s1.272.564 1.272 1.308Zm7.97 4.932v-1.14h-.912v-1.992h-1.188v1.992h-2.124l3-6.12h-1.32l-3.012 6.12v1.14h3.456V158h1.188v-1.284h.912Zm6.795 1.284-2.376-3.696 2.112-2.388h-1.488l-2.364 2.808v-5.268h-1.224V158h1.224v-1.788l.9-1.02 1.704 2.808h1.512Zm5.458-.036v-6.048h-1.188v.648c-.456-.552-.948-.72-1.596-.72-.612 0-1.128.192-1.464.528-.588.588-.684 1.44-.684 2.472s.096 1.884.684 2.472c.336.336.84.54 1.452.54.624 0 1.128-.168 1.572-.696v.78c0 .816-.396 1.548-1.428 1.548-.6 0-.936-.18-1.32-.54l-.78.78c.636.588 1.224.804 2.148.804 1.62 0 2.604-1.08 2.604-2.568Zm-1.224-3.12c0 .96-.132 1.908-1.236 1.908s-1.248-.948-1.248-1.908.144-1.908 1.248-1.908 1.236.948 1.236 1.908Z"
        fill="#ABAFBF"
      />
    </g>
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="a">
        <path fill="#fff" d="M.5 0h327v164H.5z" />
      </clipPath>
      <clipPath id="b">
        <path fill="#fff" d="M31.5 30h265v134h-265z" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
);
```

and you can pass the dimension which size do you want to.

```
<div className="icon">
 <SettingIcon size={100} />
 <ExampleIcon />
 <ExampleIcon size={100} />
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: it's not the width of the svg that i want to change, it the width of the colors, please check the post, i added a second example

Comment: I got your questions now. but it is quite not easy. I am not sure know that how do you think to set the dimension for the path of SVG? [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) I think you should find a library of charts and graph that can support what you want to do.

Comment: FYI - to show PieChartWithNeedle, pls check it out [recharts](https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/PieChartWithNeedle)